# bring the last value from a cross reference table in R

Tags: r

I have a CrossReference Table in R Like this:

```
    x   y   z   k
x   1           
y   1   2       
z   1   2   3   
k   1   2   3   4
```

I want transform it to:

```
VARIABLE    SCORE
x             1
y             2
z             3
k             4
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What are we dealing with here? a matrix, table, data.frame? Please share your data using `dput`.  Besides that: already tried `diag()`?

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice the shape of the matrix, I converted the dataframe into a matrix and then applied the diag function with the result I expected.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert it to a `data.frame` and get the `max` value

```
aggregate(Freq~ Var1, as.data.frame(tbl), max, na.rm = TRUE)
#    Var1 Freq
#1    x    1
#2    y    2
#3    z    3
#4    k    4
```

If it is based on position, use `tail`

```
aggregate(Freq~ Var1, as.data.frame(tbl), tail, 1)
```

---

Or use `pmax`

```
data.frame(VARIABLE = row.names(tbl), 
    SCORE = do.call(pmax, c(as.data.frame.matrix(tbl), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
tbl <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 
 NA, NA, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y", "z", 
 "k"), c("x", "y", "z", "k")), class = "table")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun for the answer. I need to retrive the last non NA value for each row, based on position.

Comment: @RevanKnight  You can check `aggregate(Freq~ Var1, as.data.frame(tbl), function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))`

Comment: I got lost in the part where you mention "Var1" and "Freq", my dataset is much bigger and is originally  a dataframe. Then when I apply the code I get the error message: 'Var1' not found.

Comment: @RevanKnight  I assumed that you have a `table` object.  If it is a `data.frame`, then `use `reshape2::melt(dat)` which should give a 3 column dataset i.e. `aggregate(value ~ variable, melt(as.data.frame.matrix(tbl), na.rm = TRUE), FUN = tail, 1)`